# Finding a match for an entry on a date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am looking for a query that would find all entries that have a login without a logout.

My data looks like this

```
Key     Date       Employee
LOGIN   20171225   111
LOGIN   20171225   111
LOGIN   20171226   111
There should be a record here. I need to catch that. 
LOGIN   20171227   111
LOGIN   20171227   111
```

12345  20171227   222  (There is also a LOT of other random data in the table.)

```
Select Date, Employee 
From My Table
Where Key = 'LOGIN'
Group by date, employee
Order by employee
```

I don't know how to filter out to see if there is one or two logins for that day.  I'll need to see where there's only one, because that indicates they have not logged out.  This isn't giving me the correct information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE([Key] VARCHAR(100),[Date] DATE,Employee INT);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl VALUES
 ('LOGIN','20171225',111)
,('LOGIN','20171225',111)
,('LOGIN','20171226',111)

,('LOGIN','20171227',111)
,('LOGIN','20171227',111);

SELECT *
FROM @dummyTbl
GROUP BY [Key],[Date],Employee 
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

But I wonder, why your `Key` is *LOGIN* in both cases, why not use *LOGOUT*?

Comment: Thank you. I'll test it out.  To answer your question I have no idea!  I didn't write it, and I can't change it.  It's software the company bought a long time ago.

Comment: @CNL All right, sometimes we have to eat what others have cooked :-D You'll have to add a filter for `[Key]='LOGIN'` to my solution...

Comment: Thank you. That is working.  I haven't had a chance to look at the other posters yet but I will and upvote when I can. I marked your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @CNL concerning your comment to the other answer: Using `HAVING COUNT(*) % 2 = 1` will find all odd occurances (`% 2` is *modulo 2*)

Answer (score 0):

If your key is always LogIn then you really want to look for any ODD number of entries.  Which you can do by using remainder (%) of division by 2 not equal to 0.

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE([Key] VARCHAR(100),[Date] DATE,Employee INT);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl VALUES
 ('LOGIN','20171225',111)
,('LOGIN','20171225',111)
,('LOGIN','20171226',111)
,('LOGIN','20171227',111)
,('LOGIN','20171227',111);

SELECT *
FROM @dummyTbl
GROUP BY [Key],[Date],Employee 
HAVING COUNT(*) % 2 <> 0
```

If you have multiple keys login/logout and you are attempting to figure out if the user is Logged Out then it is best to look at the last value for the user for the day and if it is not logout then you know they are still logged in.

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), [Key] VARCHAR(100),[Date] DATE,Employee INT);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl VALUES
 ('LOGIN','20171225',111)
,('LOGIN','20171225',111)
,('LOGOUT','20171225',111)
,('LOGIN','20171226',111)
,('LOGIN','20171227',111)
,('LOGOUT','20171227',111);

;WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT *
       ,LastDailyActivityRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Employee ORDER BY Id DESC)
    FROM
       @dummyTbl
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteRowNum
WHERE
    LastDailyActivityRowNum = 1
    AND [Key] = 'LOGIN'
```

If you potentially have dirty data (missing login or logout record) then it gets a bit more complicated where you will have to make some business decisions but the last record method is still generally the way to go.  When you have employees that can work past midnight without logging out then it gets a bit more complicated too.....